# Double every word that contains a substring (lets say "done") but not the substring itself

Tags: regex, shell, unix, sed

```
Example:
I have done my job well. i donett need any advice.
I have done my job well. I donett donett need any advice.
```

This is the code that i tried:

```
$ cat * | sed -E 's/\w*+done\w+*/& &/g'|  grep 'done'
```

But this code counts done as an end result as well.
I need to do it using sed.

Comment: `sed 's/\<done\w\+/& &/g' *`

Answer (score 0):

This could be easily done with `awk` in case you are ok with it.

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i !~ /^done$/ && $i ~ /done/){$i=$i OFS $i}}} 1' Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
I have done my job well. I donett donett need any advice.
```

Answer (score 0):

Or a sed-solution you asked for:

```
echo 'I have done my job well. i donett need any advice.' | sed -r 's/(\Wdone\w+|\w+done\w+|\w+done\W)/\1 \1/g; s/  / /g'
I have done my job well. i donett donett need any advice.
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using two expressions and combining them with `|`

```
$ cat * | sed -E 's/\w+done\w*|\w*done\w+/& &/g'
I have done my job well. I donett donett need any advice.
```